# Получение записей за вчера/текущие сутки

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Как получить данные за текущие сутки, и вчерашние сутки? 
Данные хранятся в *unix-timestamp.*

По-сути, если использовать `NOW() - 86400` - это будет за сутки с текущого момента. Если была бы дата вида dd.mm.yy можно было бы провести сравнение, но как быть, если используешь unixtime?

P.S. Смотрел другие вопросы по теме - либо вариант с now(), либо метод в ответе не подошел.

Comment: Смотри обновленный ответ. Говорят он лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MY_DATE_FIELD)) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

`FROM_UNIXTIME` - возвращает представление аргумента unix_timestamp как величину в формате YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS или YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, в зависимости от того, в каком контексте используется функция - в строковом или числовом

`DATE` - дает только дату, без часов,минут,секунд

Хотя вроде у `from_unixtime` можно задать сразу формат `from_unixtime(mytimestamp, '%Y-%m-%d)`

---

**UPD**. Судя по комментарию **@Mike** - лучше приводить не колонку столбца к формату, а значение, по которому ищется значение:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE MY_DATE_FIELD >= unix_timestamp(now()-interval 1 day)
```

ибо в таком случае, в отличие от первого - могут использоваться индексы. Проще процитировать конечно))

> применение функций к колонкам таблицы в сравнениях делает использование индексов невозможным и приводит к необходимости сканирования всей таблицы. Если вам нужны последние сутки, совершенно не зачем заставлять СУБД просматривать все записи за 10 лет. А раз у вас на руках unixtime то получите значение unixtime сутки назад и сравнивайте с ним

Comment: @Mike решил добавить этот комментарий в ответ. не знал, что индексы перестают работать при первом варианте и начинается fullscan. Буду знать теперь

Comment: Отлично :) Индекс построен по порядку ключей и искать в индексе или идти по диапазону можно только зная ключ по которому ищем в том виде как он в индексе. При применении любой функции к колонке БД уже не знает какой нужен ключ для получения нужного значения функции. И плюс к этому по мелочам, оптимизатор достаточно умный, вычислит значение с которым сравнивать один раз и будет сравнивать колонку с полученной константой. А если функция применяется к колонке, то ее приходится вычислять для каждой строки отдельно